# DNS - fixed IP order based on geo-location

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain with 2 servers, one in Europe and one in North America.

When a user based in North America makes a DNS request for my domain, I would like him to get both IPs from Route53, but *not* in a round-robin order.

I would like him to get the IPs in a fixed order: the North American IP first, the European one second, so that he uses the closest one if it's available.

How can I do that?

Comment: You are chasing the wrong solution. The DNS deals with sets, not lists. Your authoritative nameserver can send records back in some fixed orders, but you have absolutely no guarantee that your client, going through some recursive nameservers, will get data in the same order. GeoDNS works by having the DNS pick the most "appropriate" IP and not giving them all to the clients to choose.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek is quite correct.  "If it's available" is what Route 53 health checks are for -- they interoperate with latency-based routing so that the nearest *healthy* server's address is returned.